# Paperclip-dropbox gem not allowing access

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, paperclip, dropbox

my rails app is configured to use the app_folder access but when I try to upload a file in development, Rails throws me this error:

```
    Host: rpc.dropbox.com:443, FE: None, X-Dropbox-RequestId: None, X-Dropbox-App-Error:         None, Full Dropbox access attempt failed because this app is not configured to have full   Dropbox access.  Should your access type be app folder ('sandbox') instead?
```

At first I thought maybe I entered the value wrong. My variable looks like this:

```
    DROPBOX_ACCESS_TYPE: app_folder
```

Any ideas?

Comment: From wiki of `paperclip-dropbox` gem: `In app folder mode, every call to #url on an attachment will result in an HTTP request to Dropbox. Whether or not this is acceptable will depend on what you're storing and how you're exposing it to users.` Have you read this?

Comment: I've read it but I don't understand how it should affect uploading of a text file

Answer (score 0):

Janko, the creator of the gem solved it by telling me to update the gem